# How to make MS Access multi line

Tags: ms-access

I am storing postal addresses in an access database. How can I make it so that it is stored in the correct format so when selected using a query it will all be on separate lines?

Comment: It is far better that you store the address details across a few fields, in line with database theory. As a minimum you could separate address, city and postcode/zip.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a `TextBox`? If yes, just set the TextBox's `EnterKeyBehavior` property to `True` in code or set `Enter Key Behavior` to `New Line in Field` in the properties window (section "Other").

===

If you want to concatenate different fields in a query as a multiline string, do something like this

```sql
SELECT
    [Name] & Chr$(13) & Chr$(10) &
    [Street] & Chr$(13) & Chr$(10) &
    [City] & ' ' & [ZipCode] As AdrMultiline
FROM
    tblAddress
```

Answer (score 1):

pressing ctrl+enter will insert a line break for a textfield.  that way all data is stored in one field, but the text will be broken up into multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could put a field in the data for line number, then in the query sort on that field but do not display it.  Your source data would have a separate record for each line of the address.